# Does "arranged in direction A" make sense?

Tags: verbs

I am trying to describe that two desks are arranged side by side or next to each other in direction A while allowing the possibility that something may be located between them.  My example is as follows:

> Two desks are arranged in direction A.

Does this sentence make sense? I am afraid that using the verb "arrange" alone to describe the positional relation does not make sense, but I don't want to use "align" because this may mean that the two desks are arranged in an **exact straight** line in direction A.

Comment: You'd say (AME) something like, "The two desks sit in a row facing forward."

Comment: What @FeliniusRex. Note that the distinction you're trying to make between ***arranged = approximately** in line* and ***aligned = exactly** in line* is completely spurious (there is no such implied difference between the two words).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Uhm, no. I don't agree with the OP's wrongful distinction. I'm giving him a way to talk about the desks facing a direction without even using *arrange*.

Comment: @FeliniusRex: I don't understand. Are you disagreeing with me because you think ***arrange / align*** do in fact imply ***approximately / exactly*** respectively? I don't care whether OP uses the actual word ***arrange*** or not, but I think it would be remiss of us not to correct his misconceived distinction between the two words.

Comment: I don't agree that arrange/align imply any such thing. I ignored that issue because it is resolvable by a dictionary search.

Comment: two desks next to each other facing forward.

Comment: Let me chime in: rama9, could you add a bit more clarification so we know exactly what you want to communicate? This sentence would be accompanied by a picture; could you add a quick one? Part of the problem is that the sentence doesn't say *anything* about the "positional relation" of the desks to each other, if that's part of your intent.

Comment: (Also @FeliniusRex, I think there was a bit of a misunderstanding there because FumbleFingers' first comment was addressing the OP not you, and left out the word "said.")

Comment: @AndyBonner: Thanks for clearing that up! They always say you can't/shouldn't proofread your own work - I'd looked at the first four comments here several times without noticing that I'd missed out the word "said", but couldn't exactly figure out where we were getting our wires crossed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does this sentence make sense?** Well, especially if accompanied by a graphic, the intent is probably understood. I didn't even notice a problem until reading your final paragraph.

I think you want to change at least one of the words involved, though.

- *arranged*: This really tells us nothing about the arrangement, by itself (though the picture might). At its best, it suggests that the position of the desks is intentional. If your main point is both desks are turned to point in the same direction, then I'd replace this word with "oriented" or "facing." Note, though, two desks could be "oriented north" and still be miles apart, or one could be two feet behind the other. If you want to say something about their distance and *arrangement*, you'll need more sentences, or need to rely on the picture. (Note: you're right, "align" can talk about direction, and that it might make implications about the desks' relationship. It might make two different implications, though, without being clear about either. "Two desks are aligned facing north" does mean that you could draw a line through the center of both desks, but that line could run either north-south *or* east-west (i.e. the desks might be one behind the other, or side by side). It also still says nothing about how close they are together.)
- *direction*: I have a hard time imagining how "direction A" would be defined. If we substitute a cardinal (map) direction, or a relative direction, we'd alter the wording a bit: *Two desks are facing south.* / *Two desks are facing forward.*